# Getting a $(function() to repeat or not degrade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Long story short. I am troubleshooting my website in order for it to work properly I have to include this in the mark-up

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $ (function() {
        RESPONSIVEUI.responsiveTabs();
     });
</script>
```

What I am doing is I am taking

```
   index.html #content_container
```

and loading in my personal.html file using

```
$(".personal_info").live('click', function() {
 $("#content_container" ).load("personal/personal.html")
 $("#info").slideUp(1000, function() {
  $("menu").css("border-bottom", "#F93 2px Solid");
 });
 return false;
});
```

I am also allowing the user to return to the

```
    index.html
```

without refreshing or reloading by

```
$(".home_button").live('click', function() {
 $("#content_container").stop().load("./index.html #drill_banner")
 $("#info").slideDown(1000, function() {
  $("menu").css("border-bottom", "#F93 2px Solid")
 });

 return false;
});
```

Where you can see that it is really just loading

```
  index.html #drill_banner
```

into

```
   #content_container
```

but this drilling around degrades

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $ (function() {
        RESPONSIVEUI.responsiveTabs();
     });
</script>
```

on

```
    index.html
```

so that if you click back to "Personal" it does not load any scripts or formatting for

```
  personal.html
```

live example (use chrome) is http://www.DSTPC.ca/Beta/index.html
Click "Personal"
Click "home"
Click "Personal"

You'll see what I mean...

Comment: The jquery load command used for loading the new content supports a callback function as either the second or third argument. It is not really clear what RESPONSIVEUI.responsiveTabs() does, however if it needs to modify the document to get it to render correctly, the new content may have to go through that same manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I'm not positive as to what your responsive tab scripts are doing, but there's definitely some information you'll need to take into account to make this work.

Firstly, when you load dynamic elements into the DOM using `.load()` (or when an element is created and appended to the DOM after the DOM initially loads), you need to have some kind of `event listener` that knows how to affect those new DOM elements.

When using `.load()`, you can make use of the `callback` function like so:

```
$("#content_container").load("somepage.html", function() {
    // I am ready to do stuff with elements on `somepage.html`
});
```

In your case, you may need to both reload your "plugin" or source script, and then include your script calls *again*, like so:

```
$("#content_container").load("somepage.html", function() {
    $.getScript("some_responsive_plugin.js")
    .done(function(script, status) {
        // new script is loaded upon success
        // Make use of new script, for example maybe:
        // RESPONSIVEUI.responsiveTabs();
    });
});
```

Lastly, jQuery's `live` method [is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/live/). You're better off using jQuery's [.on() event handler](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

So, your usage might change from:

```
$(".personal_info").live('click', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

to:

```
$(".personal_info").on('click', function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Hope that helps!